# what happens to completion handler code of network operation when requesting object does not exist

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I have `VC1` which makes a network call using `NSURLSession`
- `NSURLTask` is performed in `dispatch_get_global_queue`
- `NSURLTask` has a **completionHandler** that executes code in `VC1` (delegate)
- After submitting the task, `VC1` is **popped** from *stack*.

What is the expected behavior on last statement? I mean to the network operation? How will the completionHandler get executed, if at all?

imagine the case when data is being received from server when vc1 is popped

what needs to be done to safeguard against app crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc

> The completion handler to call when the load request is complete. If sent to a session created by calling sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue: with a non-nil value for the delegateQueue parameter, this handler is executed on that delegate queue.

So, it depends if you have set a delegate or not.  If you have not set a delegate, then the object will fall out of scope and the completion block will not be called since nothing is holding a reference to the `NSURLTask`.  If you have set a delegate, it would be called on the delegate specified on the delegate queue (as noted in the doc notes)
[dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:)

Comment: yeah , so what I would say is that it shouldn't be the popped controller making the network request, it should be a separate object making the request, and that object should be retained by your original controller.  Is there a reason you want to make the network request non-blocking?  You could dismiss the view controller as part of the  completion block for your `NSURLTask`